# Show that the function $g(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^n e^{ux}}{e^x+1}dx$ is differentiable in $(0,1)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $n \geqslant 1$, Show that the function $g(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^n e^{ux}}{e^x+1}dx$ is differentiable in $(0,1)$, where $u \in (0,1)$. What I did is just use the definition of derivative, but not sure whether I can switch the limit and the integral.

Comment: There are some theorems in Lebesgue theory about differentiation under the integral.

Comment: There's a theorem in a lot of reals books that covers this... Switching the limit and the integral is the whole point. Dominated convergence should be ok here. You may want to note that $(e^{(u+h)x}-e^{ux})/h=xe^{ux}(e^{hx}-1)/(hx))$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yeah, that's what I did. The thing is after I switched the limit and integral, I got an integral which I cannot get the exact value.

Comment: ??? Why does it matter whether you can get the exact value of that integral? The problem said show the function is differentiable, not find the exact value of the derivative.

Comment: Oh, I see. thanks!

Comment: **@DavidC.Ullrich :** How would you majorate $\left|\frac{e^{hx}-1}{hx}\right|$ ?

Comment: By looking at chords on the graph of $e^v,$ you can see $(e^v-1)/v\le \max (1,e^v).$